# Customise UITabBarController.moreNavigationController UITableViewCells

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

As stated in the title, I'm trying to customise the cells in the moreNavigationController. I've read a number of SO posts asking a similar question but most are outdated and seem to be hacks.

I'm assuming this is a very common situation so there must be a 'tidy' way of doing this surely?

I've looked into overriding one of the tableviews delegate methods but I couldn't figure that out assuming it's even possible. I've also tried the following:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let moreNavController = self.moreNavigationController
    if let moreTableView = moreNavController.topViewController?.view as? UITableView {
        for cell in moreTableView.visibleCells {
            cell.textLabel?.textColor = AppDarkColor
            cell.imageView?.image = cell.imageView?.image?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
        }
    }
}
```

But moreTableView.visibleCells is empty at least when the `UITabBarController` is loaded. Maybe I need to move this somewhere else but I'm not sure where or if this is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimented putting the code in viewWillAppear. It works for me (at least). Hope it works for you!

Comment: That's what I did but forgot to post back here! Thanks for the answer anyway!